# Inputting data from cell in next column after search

Tags: excel, search, output, cell

I can't find a solution to what I need so I'm asking for help.

I have 3 columns of data I need to sort through for my project. 
Column `A` contains my search term, Column `B` is my database, Column `C` is another set of data and Column `D` would be my output.

So an example would be this: 
Cell `A1` contains `apple`. And I want to search through Column `B` for the phrase `apple`. Let's say it's found in Cell `B50`, then I want to output the value of `C50` into `D1`.

Currently I have this:

```
=if("A1"=B:B,1,0)
```

But I don't know how to output `C50` into `D1` given that the phrase is found. 
Just to be clear there are no duplicates of values anywhere.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply the VLOOKUP formula, as follows:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,B:C,2,0)
```

This looks at unique value in A1, searches for it in Column B, and gives the value from that row in the 2nd column. Searches for EXACT matches only, with 0 as the last argument.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot. I couldn't find a way to comprehensively describe what I wanted so I couldn't look up the function. But thanks for such a swift reply.

Comment: There are many ways to do this, but VLOOKUP is often considered the simplest, because you only need to give it a single value, a single range, and the column number. However remember that the '2' which refers to the 2nd column of the given Range will not move. So if you insert a column here between B&C, it will still pick the 2nd column, not what is now the 3rd column.